# CSS :: footer alignment and overflow issue

Tags: html, css

[image]

In image above you can footer top border is not aligned with the login box.I want to restrict border width equal to login container width.
and also I dont want x axis to scroll as in image.

To solve overflow issue I used,

```
html {
  overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

But it does not seems promising to me,

I want something like this ,

[image]

footer top border should be aligned with red lines

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/Pa27b/)

Comment: you copied google....!! :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute;` so you need to use `left: 0;` for the `.google-footer-bar`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa27b/2/)

```
.google-footer-bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; /* Add this here */
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Also, it will be better if you wrap up the elements, say a maximum `1000px` in `width` and than use `margin: auto;` to center them, having no wrapper element will just spoil your layout. As far as `100%` `width` element goes, you can use `width: 100%;` for the container and then nest `1000px;` of another child element with `margin: auto;`, this way your layout will be stable.

Comment: +1 Thanks for quick reply..but I want footer top border aligned to  `.product info` width

Comment: @Pilot That's what I said, set the container to `100%` which already it is, now nest another element inside that, provide some width and use `margin: auto;`, do it for entire template in this way

Comment: @Pilot I guess you are not getting what am saying, I'll create a demo structure for you

Comment: Thumbs up @Mr. Alien..Thanks for kind help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by removing width and min-width and also height and min-height.